# How to group subset of data from set of elements in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, group-by

I need to group a set of data in the table as accordingly,

There are set of **Age groups** and for each age group there are some set of **Combinations** followed by some numbers for each record. I need to group some set of elements in Combinations field.

For example, I need to group C001,C002,C003 and C004 as group and retaining rest other combinations as same.

Please find the sample data.

[image]

Comment: Please post sample data including expected result without a picture.

Comment: Sounds like a case for [CASE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/case-transact-sql)

Answer (score 1):

you can use case statement with group by to get your result -

```
select case when Combinations in ('C001','C002','C003' ,'C004' ) then 'C001' else Combinations end as Combinations  , sum(Total) 
from Age_group
group by case when Combinations in ('C001','C002','C003' ,'C004' ) then 'C001' else Combinations end
```